# Laravel dd() function not showing in Google Chrome network tab anymore how to fix it?

Tags: laravel, google-chrome

In recent versions of google chrome when dumping the result using dd function in laravel can be showed in the network tab but now it's not working anymore for some reason.

Comment: It might be worth using something like https://laravel-news.com/laravel-dump-server instead

Comment: yeah that's interesting but i don't want to install another package for just this thing

Answer (score 1):

This problem should be fixed in the latest version

Version 73.0.3683.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: using Version 100.0.4896.127 (Official Build) (64-bit). still can't see anything. Firefox is a perfect debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using Chrome version 114, and I'm facing the same issue. I haven't faced this issus with any version of Firefox, so that means the dd() function in Laravel works fine. I attempted every solution I found on the net to resolve this issus, such as adjusting the Laravel CORS configuration, adding custom headers through middleware... But unfortunately none of these methods resolved the issue.

The only effective solution I found was to install the ['Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf)' extension from the Chrome Web Store. By using this extension, I was able to fix the problem and now I can see the dd() result in the Chrome network tab.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, also experiencing the same thing, a fix would be to downgrade your google chrome to 71. Seems like there is some unfixed bug in google chrome 72.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still encountering the same problem in 2023 (Version 118.0.5993.117), you can resolve it by including the following code block in your **public/index.php**:

```
if (!function_exists('dd')) {
    /**
     * Dump the passed variables and end the script.
     *
     * @param mixed $args
     *
     * @return void
     */
     function dd(...$args)
     {
         header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
         header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
         header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');

         http_response_code(500);

         foreach ($args as $x) {
            (new Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper())->dump($x);
         }

        die(1);
    }
}
```

If you are using Laravel Sanctum SPA and making API requests with cookies, you will need to include the following headers:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://localhost:8080'));
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

**Note:** It's essential to be aware that the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header should not use a wildcard ("*") when handling cross-origin requests.